# How can they see Harry's invisibility cloak when they are not wearing it?

Tags: harry-potter

When no one was wearing the invisibility cloak, how could they find it? Wouldn't it be invisible? I read through [this](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Invisibility) and it explained its history, strengths and weaknesses, but didn't really answer my question.

Comment: Perhaps the magic cloak is magic in that way? ;)

Comment: My thoughts were that maybe it knows when it's covering someone. Just wasn't sure if it was explained anywhere.

Comment: Kind of nit-picky - but it is an invisibility cloak... not an invisible cloak.

Comment: True, but it does become invisible, from a certain point of view.

Comment: The interior of the coat is not invisible only the exterior renders the wearer invisible.  Should it be worn inside out, it would look like a common coat.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The cloak is visible from one side.  If you look at the scene where Harry gets it for a present, you can see it from the "inside" side.

While there are no actual clips from the movie on YouTube, [here is the scene](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KGef_urjAl8) done in Rifftrax.

You can also see it in the picture in the Harry Potter wiki article on the [invisibility cloak](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Invisibility_cloak) (which you linked to).  Granted, the wiki doesn't address it, and at first glance at that first image of it, the design is kind of funky (Rifftrax describes it as "tie-dye velvet") so it's hard to be sure you're seeing the inside of the cloak, but if you watch the scene in the movie, it's clear the cloak is visible from the inside.

Comment: So he has to be careful when putting it away to make sure the visible side is up? Maybe it's on the washing and care instruction label.

Comment: Or he has to be sure he knows where he's put it.  Seriously, if you had such a cloak, wouldn't you not only make sure it goes where nobody could find it, but also make sure you remembered where you put it?  It's not like it's an old book you read once and don't care about.  Heck, this thing's a bigger deal than several hundred in cash -- and if you've got that much laying around, don't you know where it is?

Comment: I agree, I wouldn't let it out of my sight. But he also seems to be in danger quite a lot. Its possible in a rush he might throw it off to defend himself, etc. I doubt he'd be careful and fold it up nicely when he's facing down a dementor.

Comment: You wouldn't let an invisibility cloak out of your sight. That is funny. But seriously, people lose important stuff all the time; keys, remotes, cars, pets, spouses, kids, homework, etc (the list is virtually endless). While some of these things may be lost longer than others, we can see all of them so finding them again is easier. I imagine invisible objects being lost much more thoroughly.

Comment: Couldn't he just `Accio Invisibility Cloak!` ?

Comment: I remember from the movie, that it's invisible from one side, and only transparent from the other side.

Comment: @vsz: Isn't that what I said in my answer?

Comment: @TangoOversway: "Seriously, if you had such a cloak, wouldn't you not only make sure it goes where nobody could find it, but also make sure you remembered where you put it?" From that I can only conclude that you don't have kids. I have quite a few, and I can assure you that at a cloak that cannot be seen would take about 10mins to get lost with kids, maybe 30mins if they are teenagers. `:(`

Comment: @sbi: Three words: Lock, key, chest.

Comment: @TangoOversway: Forget it. The kids would mislay the key within a few minutes.

Comment: Harry also loses his invisiblity cloak at least twice during the series.

Comment: @DylanYaga I don't know if Harry can accio the cloak, but in The Deathly Hallows, a death eater tries that while Harry is wearing the cloak and it doesn't work.

Comment: @DylanYaga The Cloak (at least Harry's) can definitely not be accioed, because it is one of the Deathly Hallows!

Answer (score 4):

From the first time Harry (and we) were introduced to the cloak

> This only left one parcel. Harry picked it up and felt it. It was very
>   light. He unwrapped it.
>   Something fluid and silvery gray went slithering to the floor where it
>   lay in gleaming folds. Ron gasped.
>   "I've heard of those," he said in a hushed voice, dropping the box of
>   Every Flavor Beans he'd gotten from Hermione. "If that's what I think it
>   is -- they're really rare, and really valuable."
>   "What is it?"
>   Harry picked the shining, silvery cloth off the floor. It was strange to
>   the touch, like water woven into material.
>   "It's an invisibility cloak," said Ron, a look of awe on his face. "I'm
>   sure it is -- try it on."

JKR keeps up this description all through the books.  So you can definitely see it (it also seems to feel differently than normal material).

Answer (score 2):

I thought that the cloak was just a cloak until it was put over someone and it then, for want of a better phrase, engaged it's cloaking device.

Otherwise how could it be made (how do you stitch something that cannot be seen?  When you come back in the morning, how do you know where you got to?)?

What if you dropped it?

I am not sure whether this is mentioned tbh but it is the only thing that makes sense to me.  Have the cloak visable from one side and not the other does not sit right in my mind, what if it fell invisible side up?  What if the cloak was twisted and the invisible side up was caught under something, you would rip it when you tried to pick it up.

Answer (score 2):

One side of the cloak was not visible.

[image: Harry receiving the cloak from Albus Dumbledore as Christmas gift]

Borrowed from http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Cloak_of_Invisibility

Comment: Brought to you by the same people who worked out the logic on Bugs Bunny's portable holes :-)

Comment: Quite interesting: In this shot you can actually see in the lower left corner of the cloak, a piece of it's green backside, which was used to make Harry's body invisible in the movie.